# Writing dataframe to blob storage - file either empty or job aborted

Tags: azure-databricks

I'm trying to write a simple dataframe containing some string types as a csv and store it in my blob storage container. I've mounted the blob container in workspace using a SAS that has both read and write permissions and is not expired. I also want it to be a single file so used coalesce(1) but is coming out as PART-1, PART-0.

Here's my code

```
file_path_blob = "/mnt/LogData/predictions1"
anomalies_df.coalesce(1).write.csv(file_path_blob)
```

When I run the job it writes something but eventually fails ...with an error message like

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException.translateException(StorageException.java:89)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.StorageRequest.materializeException(StorageRequest.java:305)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:178)
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlob.delete(CloudBlob.java:928)
    at shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.StorageInterfaceImpl$CloudBlobWrapperImpl.delete(StorageInterfaceImpl.java:313)
    at shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.safeDelete(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:2533)
    at shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.rename(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:2727)
    ... 28 more
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: How are you connecting to blob storage? Is it mounted to that location?

Comment: Hi Jon, yes it is. I've mounted it to /mnt/LogData in DBFS using the shared access signature of the container

Comment: If you want just a true single file it is probably best to use the Azure SDK and pandas to upload it.